# Reading from .CSV file in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to read data from .CSV file. I have written the following code, I need to read 3 columns of data. One of them is to be considered as boolean the following is my data in the CSV.

21  1    false
53  12   true
50  21   true
1   0    false

So, Based on the boolean value in the last columns in trying to apply different actions in the if loop. I'm new to the java environment can someone assist me in achieving.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    // use comma as separator
                    String[] separator = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                    totalPapers = Integer.parseInt(separator[0]);
                    totalColors = Integer.parseInt(separator[1]);
                    if (total_papers[2] == "true"){
                        isDoublePrints = true;
                    }
                    isDoublePrints = Boolean.parseBoolean(total_papers[2]);
                    System.out.println(isDoublePrints);
                    if(isDoublePrints == true){
                        totalPapers = (int) (totalBW * 0.12);
                        totalColors = (int) (totalColors * 0.13);

                    }
                    else{
                        totalPapers = (int) (totalBW * 0.24);
                        totalColors = (int) (totalColors * 0.22);

                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Whenever I run this program the compiler is getting the to the else. even though there are true values in the last column of my CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[noteDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

this method can set the data you want to send to your server. your server received a string `"http://domain/Customer_logon.php?  email=XXXX&password=XXXX"`,the string is not a valid json, your php can not parse it.

so,if you need a json,you can write like this:

```
NSString *email = cusemail.text;
NSString *pass  = cuspassword.text;
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"email":email,@"password":pass};
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:0 error:nil]];
```

Comment: Still getting the same error i thing the there is a problem with PHP. because it is showing in the error log PHP Notice:  Undefined index:

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: email

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password as well

Comment: sorry bro i was away from desk . . have added the php code in the same post. please have a look

Comment: I have post a new answer

Answer (score 0):

`$email = isset($_GET['email']);` this mean that you receive parameter by `GET`, but the objc code send parameter by `POST`. **you'd better to learn about the difference between GET and POST first**. if you user $_GET in php to receive param,you should write like this in objc:

````
    NSString *email = cusemail.text;
    NSString *pass  = cuspassword.text;
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domain/Customer_logon.php?email=%@&password=%@",email,pass];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *dataRaw, NSURLResponse *header, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:dataRaw
                              options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSString *status = json[@"status"];

        if([status isEqual:@"1"]){
            //Success

        } else {
            //Error

        }
    }];```
````